# How to check whether device set vibration mode or not in iOS programatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone-vibrate

I am making a VoIP application for iOS. For incoming calls, I have set some custom ringtones. It's working fine, but I want to check whether the device settings are set to Vibration mode or not programmatically.

I have searched on the web regarding this issue, but I've only found answers for silent mode detection. Instead, I want to check whether the device is in vibration mode or not.

When an incoming call comes to my app, I want to use vibration mode if the device settings are set to vibration mode.

Could any one help me?

Comment: Follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054696/can-i-determine-how-if-a-device-has-vibration-or-not

Comment: @AkashKR thanks for your answer, but my query is, I want to detect iPhone settings set "Vibration on Ring" yes or not status by programatically. But, not device can vibrate or not.

Comment: Check [http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520469/5575752](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5520469/5575752)

Comment: @RonakChaniyara, thanks for your answer, but, its getting device is in silent mode or not.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper did you able to get this answer?

Comment: @Shohrab, not yet, but we cant get due to its privacy of apple.

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper is it possible using Private API?

Comment: @Shohrab, i dint found yet, if i would found, will post here!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19295480/iphone-programmatically-check-if-vibration-is-enabled seems this is not available :/

Answer (score 0):

At first look it seems like none of the Audio Session properties allow you to read the value of this setting. However an alternative, albeit not exactly what you're looking for, is to check if the ringer is set to on-or-off and provide at least a semi-expected vibration experience to your user.

Ronak Chaniyara pointed you to the right answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519807/iphone-how-do-i-know-if-the-vibrate-is-on-or-off-for-ios/5520469#5520469), however that is deprecated in iOS 7.0. Instead use `AVAudiSession -setCategory` to set the proper category of your audio. If you expect your audio to be muted by the silent switch or screen lock use `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` otherwise use `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback`.

More details on AVAudioSession, it's settings and properties can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioSession/otherAudioPlaying).